# Class referenced in the layout file, `androidx.constraintlayout.widget`, was not found in the project or the libraries

Tags: android, android-studio, dependencies, android-constraintlayout, android-appcompat

hey everyone btw it's my first question in StackOverflow hope you help me find the answer.
I tried to add recycler view to my **android studio arctic fox v2020.3.1** from tab File>Project Structure > Dependencies. then l clicked on the + button to add `"androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1"` to my app and I`ve searched and applied it then I came back to using it and I noticed thousands of redlines under every code and most of them couldn't find or resolve something as below:[errors 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylGYQ.png) [errors 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQjmd.png)

I tried to delete dependencies and recall them nothing happened I also tried restarting Android Studio, nothing I use the latest JDK and etc

[code with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvz7W.png)

Comment: Can you upload the code for `build.gradle` project and `build.gradle` app?

Comment: You should upload code in a proper formatting, not screens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for all of those that are faced with this problem I hope this helps you because I fixed it with `toggle offline mode` of Gradle somehow my Gradle version changed during few days of using it in offline mode and I`ve forgotten that to change it back so when I was trying to add new dependency it comes with this problem and you can fix it by [clicking on Gradle tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IPru.png),   [switching off the toggle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKJZt.png) and syncing your project with Gradle files again.

thanks to those who wanted to help.

Comment: Excellent.!! . From last 8 days i'm googling but my issue not resolved. Now its resolved with your tips. Thank You..!!

Comment: It's my pleasure

Answer (score 1):

This message happened to me when I made a typo in layout xml file, I had a wrong hand on the keyboard:
[image]

I typed androidx.**tappcompat** instead of androidx.**appcompat**