# Cannot resolve class error when using library from GitHub

Tags: android, xml, maven, github

I want to use this library: https://github.com/rongi/rotate-layout

However I get the following errors when I use the code below in my project:

```
Class referenced in the layout file, com.github.rongi.rotate_layout.layout.RotateLayout, was not found in the project or the libraries
Cannot resolve class com.github.rongi.rotate_layout.layout.RotateLayout
```

I used `implementation ("rongi.rotate-layout:rotate-layout:3.0.0")` and `implementation ("com.github.rongi.rotate-layout:rotate-layout:3.0.0")`

```
<com.github.rongi.rotate_layout.layout.RotateLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:angle="90"> <!-- Specify rotate angle here -->
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdRE3.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68942599/15298643

Comment: @javdromero this did not solve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library is quite old and [wasn't migrated to the Maven Central repository](https://github.com/rongi/rotate-layout/issues/16), since JCenter was deprecated.

But you can use it from [Jitpack repository](https://jitpack.io/#rongi/rotate-layout/v3.0.0):

1. Add it in your root build.gradle at the end of repositories:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

2. Add the dependency to your app build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.rongi:rotate-layout:v3.0.0'
}
```

Comment: hi, I still get the error with these changes, did you test it?

Comment: Yes, it's resolved for my project.
Double-check that you use `v3.0.0` instead of `3.0.0` for the dependency.

Comment: I still do, unfortunately.  I added a screenshot from my layout file

Comment: my project syncs successfully but the layout file appears as red like in the screenshot

Comment: [Screenshot][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdRE3.png

Comment: Can you show your root and app build.gradle files?

Comment: which parts of those files

Comment: where you set `maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }` and `implementation 'com.github.rongi:rotate-layout:v3.0.0'`